# Updating values of SQL column with values from the same column

Tags: sql-server-2008

[image: data]

If you will look at the image above. I need to update this table for the null values of the TID which is column third in the table, with the values in between two rows that actually has value.

So in the above example, I need to have rows 44-57 as 040, row 60-87 as 077 etc. One pattern that could be used is that column 2 has INS in the string, which denotes that the value in column 3 is to be changed. So I was thinking about using DATA LIKE 'INS%' in some way.

Please let me know what you think of the problem and any possible solutions.

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL complex logic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473835/sql-complex-logic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @x TABLE
(Column1 INT, Column2 VARCHAR(64), TID VARCHAR(10));

INSERT @x VALUES
(42, 'INS{whatever}', '040'),
(43, 'somethingelse', '040'),
(44, 'somethingelse', NULL),
(45, 'somethingelse', NULL),
(46, 'somethingelse', NULL),
(47, 'somethingelse', NULL),
(48, 'somethingelse', NULL),
(49, 'INS{whatever}', '077'),
(50, 'somethingelse', '077'),
(51, 'somethingelse', NULL),
(52, 'somethingelse', NULL);

;WITH x AS (SELECT i = Column1, TID, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column1)
    FROM @x WHERE Column2 LIKE 'INS%'
),
y AS (SELECT x.TID, s = x.i, e = COALESCE(x2.i, 2000000000)
FROM x LEFT OUTER JOIN x AS x2 ON x.rn = x2.rn -1
)
UPDATE src SET TID = y.TID
FROM @x AS src
INNER JOIN y ON src.Column1 > y.s AND src.Column1 < y.e;

SELECT * FROM @x;
```

Comment: May you please explain the logic. I am trying to do something similar for another problem. 

Thanks!

Comment: First cte (x) takes the values where Column2 = `INS<someting>`, second cte (y) does a self-join to that so it can determine which rows are subsequent to the "first" row for that. The coalesce is there because there can never be a row that is *after* the "last" row in the table - I assumed that your table wouldn't have 2 billion IDs. Then it applies the original TID value for all the subsequent rows that are greater than the "first" row for that TID and less than the first row for the first "different" TID.

Comment: I still can't understand the logic completely, but I was able to manipulate it to resolve the other two problems. I have to say I use to think I was smart and then I meet you. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

This assumes that:

- The first two columns in your sample were duplicated (I ignore the first listed)
- Col1 is a primary key
- Values are to be assigned as you described based on ascending values in Col1
- Performance might be bad to very bad on large tables
- Performance would improve with suitable indexing (on Col1 and Col3)

Substitute in your table and column names, and check for minor typos.

```
UPDATE MyTable
 set Col3 = mt2.Col3
 from MyTable mt
  inner join (--  Get the "earlier" Col3 value for each row that has no value
              select t1.Col1, max(t2.Col1) EarlierValueHere
               from MyTable t1
                inner join MyTable t2
                 on t2.Col1 < t1.Col1
                  and t2.Col3 is not null
               group by t1.Col1
               where t1.Col3 is null) earlier
   on earlier.Col1 = mt.Col1
  inner join MyTable mt2
   on mt2.Col1 = earlier.EarlierValueHere
```

Answer (score 0):

Another query you might use:

```
update t set TID = X.NonNullTID
from [YourTable] t
join 
    (select 
        t1.Column1, t1.Column2, t1.TID, 
        (select top 1 tid from [YourTable]
            where TID is not null and Column1 <= t1.Column1 
            order by Column1 desc) as NonNullTID
    from [YourTable] t1) X
    on X.Column1 = t.Column1
```